# Getting error: dyld: Symbol not found: _clock_gettime

Tags: ruby, middleman

I want to start a middleman with command *middleman server* and when I do I get an error:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _clock_gettime
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.0.1/lib/rubyeventmachine.bundle (which was built for Mac OS X 10.12)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _clock_gettime
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.0.1/lib/rubyeventmachine.bundle (which was built for Mac OS X 10.12)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

This has something to do with livereload, because when I remove it it works.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: This seems related to Xcode 8 on El Capitan (10.11). It should work on Sierra (10.12).

Comment: Things resolved when I upgraded to macOS

Comment: that's not acceptable: I don't want to upgrade my OS just to get this code working. I think what happened is that I upgraded Xcode and then tried to run an existing project. Rebuilding the project now to see if that fixes the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same `dyld: Symbol not found: _clock_gettime` error message during an attempted install of ruby 2.3.1 on El Capitan.

The advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39302619/missing-symbol-when-installing-ruby-2-3-0-on-os-x-10-11-6-by-rvm) to run `xcode-select --install` and allow the xcode command line tools to reinstall solved that issue for me.

If you're using that version of OS X perhaps it may help you as well?

Comment: I tried these steps but they are not working. I'm using 10.11.6. Can you propose some other solution?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what the issue may be if that doesn't resolve it

Answer (score -1):

install brew first,
please enter：
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

please enter：

brew doctor

according to the prompt operation,Probably appear “sudo xcode-select --install” ，please do it, if appear "Your system is ready to brew.",that is ok，Re input “ram install 2.3" ,that is ok,good luck ,Please don't mind my English。。。。。