# How to downgrade command line tools MacOS

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode-command-line-tools

I got a dynamic linker error with the `__clock_gettime` symbol so I did what this post said [Missing symbol when installing ruby-2.3.0 on OS X 10.11.6 by RVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39302619/missing-symbol-when-installing-ruby-2-3-0-on-os-x-10-11-6-by-rvm) (i.e. `xcode-select --install`) and now I am getting loader errors that say that libraries were built for a newer OS version than the one I am currently running on,  I dont want to upgrade my OS to the newer (Sierra) version though, is there a way you can downgrade the command line tools to an older version (10.11?)

Comment: Has anyone tried using `xcode-select`? Is this something that it can do? I already deleted Xcode before I noticed that xcode-select exists.

Answer (score 8):

It's unclear which version of Xcode you are using, although it is possible to have multiple versions of the command-line tools installed, which can be selected in Xcode Preferences.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Command Line tools come with Xcode.  If you delete and downgrade Xcode it should do the trick.  Once you delete Xcode from you applications, use "Previous versions of Xcode can also be downloaded here" link in https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/.
**SPOILER ALERT: You need to have/create an apple dev account for this**

Answer (score 1):

Can download command line tools without the complete Xcode application here: https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=command%20line%20tools