# How to downgrade Xcode command line tools without Apple dev account or Xcode IDE?

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode-command-line-tools

I have Xcode command line tools 8.3 and I want to downgrade to version 8.2 without installing the IDE. Is there any way I can do this?

Using macOS Sierra 10.12.4. I don't have an Apple developer license.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to downgrade command line tools MacOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41327298/how-to-downgrade-command-line-tools-macos)

Comment: @samiles I am specifically asking how to do this without Xcode or an Apple dev account

Comment: You want to downgrade Xcode... without Xcode?

Comment: @samiles As I said I want to downgrade Xcode command line tools. You can have the command line tools without the IDE