# dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _clock_gettime - in mongodb laravel

Tags: php, mongodb, macos, laravel-5.3

I am using Laravel 5.4 version to implement mongodb CRUD operation using [link](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb). I am using Mac OS El Captain 10.11. I have installed mongodb.so extension with php version 7.1.16

While i am trying getting eloquent connection it throws me **ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE**

I have digg in details an found following error log in Apache during restart the MAMP server

```
 Mon Aug 28 10:22:14 2017] [notice] Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Mon Aug 28 10:22:15 2017] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Mon Aug 28 10:22:15 2017] [notice] Digest: done
[Mon Aug 28 10:22:15 2017] [notice] Apache/2.2.31 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.5 
 Python/2.7.13 PHP/7.1.1 mod_ssl/2.2.31 OpenSSL/1.0.2j DAV/2 
mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_perl/2.0.9 Perl/v5.24.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Aug 28 10:22:15 2017] [notice] FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid 4233)
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _clock_gettime
Referenced from: 
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.1/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/mongodb.so
Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _clock_gettime
Referenced from: 
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.1/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/mongodb.so
Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _clock_gettime
Referenced from: 
 /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.1/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/mongodb.so
 Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _clock_gettime
Referenced from: 
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.1/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/mongodb.so
 Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

This screenshot shows the details of mongodb extension
[image]
I have searched online for error `dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _clock_gettime` and found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39674711/1578380). I have applied all steps which i mentioned, but unable to fix the issue.

Please someone help me to get rid of this.

Comment: What install are you using on `mac OS`? Are you using `brew`?

Comment: Yes, i am using brew, and OS X Al Captain

Comment: This is going to be an ever-changing answer as we troubleshoot your problem. Start with this in `terminal`: brew update && brew upgrade && brew doctor

Comment: Thanks for reply, but update and upgrade is not working, it's still showing me ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Answer (score 6):

First of you need to update your os to macOS Sierra, (I am using version 10.12)

clock_gettime was not provided in El Capitain,

Apple has (finally) introduced the clock_gettime posix API in Sierra. Our configure script detects this and enable usage of it. Since the binary isn't executed on Sierra, but instead on El Capitain where this functionality doesn't exist, the linking in runtime fails. Using the workaround you suggest is not a good solution. This might seemingly work, but it is not impossible that you get strange failures at a later time since the binary isn't compiled for the system it is executing on.

Reference From : https://bugs.erlang.org/browse/ERL-256

Comment: Thanks, @Mehul Panchasara I am afraid, why i have to upgrade my OS just for one clock_gettime binaray

Comment: @Chintan7027 Upgrading your OS will help to install libraries which are missing in your current OS,
You can install those libraries manually but it would be a tedious task though.

Comment: How can "Upgrade your system" be a valid answer?

Comment: Upgrading my system is out of the question because my hardware is too old for anything newer than El Cap.

Answer (score 1):

Latest versions of php{XX}-mongodb installed from homebrew rely on the use of a OS X 10.12 specific Symbol called `_clock_gettime`, which did not exists in OS X < 10.12.

Upgrading your system will solve this problem, but you might have some *valid* reasons to not wish to upgrade it.

There is a pull-request currently being Work-In-Progress to preserve the OS X 10.11 compatibility :

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/3737

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/pull/3890

While this is not accepted, you can hack the `phpXX-mongodb` formula yourself, [as nicely suggested by @adocwang here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/3737#issuecomment-279932413) :

(Be sure to install xcode-select tools first)

```
sudo xcode-select --install
# Or if you already installed it
softwareinstall --install -a
```

Then edit the php{XX}-mongodb formula (that'll be `php71-mongogb`, `php56-mongodb`, or whatever PHP version you're using)

```
brew edit php{XX}-mongodb
```

Find the line of "def install", and replace

```
def install
  Dir.chdir "mongodb-#{version}" unless build.head?
```

By

```
def install
  Dir.chdir "mongodb-#{version}" unless build.head?

  if MacOS.version == "10.11" && MacOS::Xcode.installed? && MacOS::Xcode.version >= "8.0"
    inreplace %w[src/libbson/src/bson/bson-clock.c], "HAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME", "UNDEFINED_GIBBERISH"`
  end
```

Then force the reinstallation of this formula from source

```
brew reinstall -s php{XX}-mongodb
```

Comment: Ok, i have to try this options