# BUILD FAILED Error When Trying to Install Ruby 2.4.2

Tags: ruby, build, terminal, installation, failed-installation

I'm trying to install Ruby. I've already installed `rbenv`. After running the command
`rbenv install 2.4.2`

I get the following message

```
BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.12.6 using ruby-build 20170914)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/7s/pm59xf21247gd16zvrxmjfkwz6thn7/T/ruby-build.20170927101212.49499
Results logged to /var/folders/7s/pm59xf21247gd16zvrxmjfkwz6thn7/T/ruby-build.20170927101212.49499.log

Last 10 log lines:
Generating RDoc documentation
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _utimensat
  Referenced from: /private/var/folders/7s/pm59xf21247gd16zvrxmjfkwz6thn7/T/ruby-build.20170927101212.49499/ruby-2.4.2/./ruby
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _utimensat
  Referenced from: /private/var/folders/7s/pm59xf21247gd16zvrxmjfkwz6thn7/T/ruby-build.20170927101212.49499/ruby-2.4.2/./ruby
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

make: *** [rdoc] Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: Can you check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39302619/missing-symbol-when-installing-ruby-2-3-0-on-os-x-10-11-6-by-rvm

Comment: Nope, it says it's already installed.

Comment: I use RVM and I got the same error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Figured it out. Error is resolved by running `xcode-select --install`.

See https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/4809

Comment: Why not accept this answer as correct? BTW, this worked for me!