# Getting error trying to upgrade Ruby to latest version on MacOS Sierra

Tags: ruby

I was reading the instructions from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38194032/how-to-update-ruby-version-2-0-0-to-the-latest-version-in-mac-osx-yosemite) on upgrading Ruby on MacOS using `rvm`, but ran into the following issue(s) when I used `rvm install ruby-2.4.2`:

[image]

```
[2017-10-01 21:09:50] __rvm_make
__rvm_make () 
{ 
    \make "$@" || return $?
}
current path: /Users/jeff/.rvm/src/ruby-2.4.2
PATH=/usr/local/opt/coreutils/bin:/usr/local/opt/pkg-config/bin:/usr/local/opt/libtool/bin:/usr/local/opt/automake/bin:/usr/local/opt/autoconf/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/jeff/.rvm/bin
command(2): __rvm_make install
++ make install
generating x86_64-darwin16-fake.rb
x86_64-darwin16-fake.rb updated
    CC = gcc
    LD = ld
    LDSHARED = gcc -dynamiclib
    CFLAGS = -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-self-assign -Wunused-variable -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens   -fno-common -pipe 
    XCFLAGS = -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -fno-strict-overflow -fvisibility=hidden -DRUBY_EXPORT
    CPPFLAGS = -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -I. -I.ext/include/x86_64-darwin16 -I./include -I. -I./enc/unicode/9.0.0
    DLDFLAGS = -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup -Wl,-multiply_defined,suppress -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -install_name /Users/jeff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/lib/libruby.2.4.2.dylib -compatibility_version 2.4 -current_version 2.4.2  -fstack-protector -Wl,-u,_objc_msgSend -framework CoreFoundation  -fstack-protector -Wl,-u,_objc_msgSend -framework CoreFoundation  
    SOLIBS = -lpthread -ldl -lobjc 
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.37)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
generating enc.mk
making srcs under enc
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `srcs'.
generating transdb.h
transdb.h unchanged
generating makefile exts.mk
*** Following extensions failed to configure:
../.././ext/gdbm/extconf.rb:0: Failed to configure gdbm. It will not be installed.
*** Fix the problems, then remove these directories and try again if you want.
make[2]: `ruby' is up to date.
making enc
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `enc'.
making trans
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `./enc/trans'.
making encs
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `encs'.
./miniruby -I./lib -I. -I.ext/common  ./tool/runruby.rb --extout=.ext  -- --disable-gems -r./x86_64-darwin16-fake ./tool/rbinstall.rb --make="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make" --dest-dir="" --extout=".ext" --mflags="" --make-flags="" --data-mode=0644 --prog-mode=0755 --installed-list .installed.list --mantype="doc"
installing binary commands:   /Users/jeff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/bin
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _utimensat
  Referenced from: /Users/jeff/.rvm/src/ruby-2.4.2/libruby.2.4.2.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _utimensat
  Referenced from: /Users/jeff/.rvm/src/ruby-2.4.2/libruby.2.4.2.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

make: *** [do-install-nodoc] Abort trap: 6
++ return 2
```

I'm using MacOS Sierra v.10.12.6

Comment: Can you please dump a copy of the install.log file whose path is in the red error at the bottom of your screenshot (at least the significant parts of it) ?

Comment: @aurelienshz I updated my post, sorry about that.

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39302619/missing-symbol-when-installing-ruby-2-3-0-on-os-x-10-11-6-by-rvm ? Looks like you need to install development dependencies that come packaged with XCode for rvm to work correctly. Makes sense, since rvm tells you that you're building ruby from source instead of using a packaged binary.

Comment: @aurelienshz it works now, thanks for pointing me to the right direction! I had already installed Xcode, but I hadn't installed the XCode Command Line Tools.